# Improving my "Guess Who?" game

Tags: java, swing

I have a project in school.  This is the game that I've created, but I need to make some improvements. I put a `swing.timer` inside the action event to create a score/time decrements effects.  But, I have a problem because there is a textfield inside the frame and I can't type any words there because of the `timer.setRepeats(true)`.

This is the only way that I know at the moment.  If you have some problem in understanding my code, please tell me and I will try to explain.  I need some improvement/suggestion for my program.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Puzzle extends JFrame {
    /**
     * author: Victor Emmanuel C. Estomo
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    static int l = 1;
    static int sx = 100000;
    static int sx1 = 10000 ;
    static int tx = 4060;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Frame
        final JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setTitle("Picture Puzzle");
        f.setSize(500,500);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);

        //panels in the game

        //start panels
        final JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        final JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        final JPanel p20 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        final JPanel p3 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        final JPanel p4 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        // first picture panels
        final JPanel p5 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        final JPanel p50 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        final JPanel p6 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        // first picture panels --30 seconds
        final JPanel p1stblur01 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        final JPanel p1stblur02 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        final JPanel p1stblur03 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        // first picture panels --60 seconds
        final JPanel p2ndblur01 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        final JPanel p2ndblur02 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        final JPanel p2ndblur03 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        // second picture panels
        final JPanel p7 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        final JPanel p70 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        final JPanel p501 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        // second picture panels --30 seconds
        final JPanel p3rdblur01 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        final JPanel p3rdblur02 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        final JPanel p3rdblur03 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        // second picture panels --60 seconds
        final JPanel p4thblur01 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        final JPanel p4thblur02 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        final JPanel p4thblur03 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        // third picture panels
        final JPanel p8 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        final JPanel p80 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        final JPanel p502 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        // fourth picture panels
        final JPanel p9 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        final JPanel p90 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        final JPanel p503 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        // last picture panels
        final JPanel p10 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        final JPanel p100 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        final JPanel p504 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());          

        //p1 components (Main frame)
        ImageIcon titlepicture = new ImageIcon("C:\\java pics\\jigsaw.png");
        JLabel title = new JLabel(titlepicture);
        JButton start = new JButton("   Start  ");
        JButton about = new JButton("  About ");
        JButton credits = new JButton("Credits");

        //p2,p20 components (start frame)
        ImageIcon loading = new ImageIcon("C:\\java pics\\loading.gif");
        JLabel startLoading = new JLabel(loading);
        JButton continue1 = new JButton("Continue");

        //p3 components (about frame)
        JLabel aboutmsg = new JLabel("About the Game:");
        JLabel aboutlabel = new JLabel("<html>1. This game is just for fun."
                + "<br>2. You need to solve the puzzle to continue."
                + "<br>3. Each level has a corresponding difficulty."
                + "<br>4. Enjoy the game.</html>");
        JButton back1f1 = new JButton("Back");

            //p4 components(credits frame)
        JLabel creditmsg1 = new JLabel("<html>Victor Emmanuel Estomo"
            + "<br>Ferdinand Gelle"
            + "<br>Marthie Lim</html>");
        JLabel creditmsg2 = new JLabel("Created by:");
        JButton back2f1 = new JButton("Back");

        //---first picture---//

        f.revalidate();
        f.repaint();
   }
}
```

I've updated my code, and I hope I'm doing this right.  This time I removed all the components in the mainframe.  This code is 100% running but 40% done. Give me some suggestion to improve my game.

```
package projects;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class GuessingGame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static JPanel startpanel;
private static JPanel aboutpanel;
private static JPanel creditpanel;
private static JPanel loadingEffect;
private static JPanel LST;
private static JPanel LSTfinal;
private static JPanel Next0Prev;
private JPanel loadingEffectBtn;
private JPanel firstPicblur;
private JPanel firstPicblurA;
private JPanel firstPiclabelA;
private ImageIcon guess,loading;
private JLabel    title,aboutmsg,aboutlabel,creditmsg,creditlabel,startLoading,level01,score01,time01,clueNo1;
private JButton start,about,credits,back2f1A,back2f1B,continueButton,Next,Prev;
private JTextField TypeHere;
static int gTime = 1000;
static int gScore = 1000000;

public GuessingGame(){
//Title page    
startpanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());   
guess = new ImageIcon("C:\\java pics\\jigsaw.png");
title = new JLabel(guess);
start = new JButton("   Start  ");
about = new JButton("  About  ");
credits = new JButton(" Credits");

GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
c.gridx = 200;
c.gridy = 150;
startpanel.add(title,c);
c.gridx = 200;
c.gridy = 250;
startpanel.add(start,c);
c.gridx = 200;
c.gridy = 300;
startpanel.add(about,c);
c.gridx = 200;
c.gridy = 350;
startpanel.add(credits,c);

//About page
aboutpanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
aboutmsg = new JLabel("About the Game");
aboutlabel = new JLabel("This game is created for educational purpose");
back2f1A = new JButton("Back");

c.gridx = 100;
c.gridy = 5;
aboutpanel.add(aboutmsg,c);
c.gridx = 100;
c.gridy = 100;
aboutpanel.add(aboutlabel,c);
c.gridx = 100;
c.gridy = 150;
aboutpanel.add(back2f1A,c);

//Credit page
creditpanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
creditmsg = new JLabel("Created by");
creditlabel = new JLabel("estomo, Lim ,gelle");
back2f1B = new JButton("Back");

c.gridx = 100;
c.gridy = 5;
creditpanel.add(creditmsg,c);
c.gridx = 100;
c.gridy = 150;
creditpanel.add(creditlabel,c);
c.gridx = 100;
c.gridy = 200;
creditpanel.add(back2f1B,c);

//loading effect
loadingEffect = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
loadingEffectBtn = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
loading = new ImageIcon("C:\\java pics\\loading.gif");
startLoading = new JLabel(loading);
continueButton = new JButton("Continue");

c.gridx = 200;
c.gridy = 150;
loadingEffect.add(startLoading,c);
c.gridx = 200;
c.gridy = 250;
loadingEffectBtn.add(continueButton,c);

//first picture
LST = new JPanel();
level01 = new JLabel("Level: 1");
score01 = new JLabel("Score :__");
time01 = new JLabel("Time :__");

LST.add(level01);
LST.add(score01);
LST.add(time01);

//Next0Prev 
Next0Prev = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
Next = new JButton("NEXT");
Prev = new JButton("PREV");
TypeHere = new JTextField("Guess Who");
clueNo1 = new JLabel("Picture Number 01");

Next0Prev.add(Next,BorderLayout.EAST);
Next0Prev.add(Prev,BorderLayout.WEST);
Next0Prev.add(TypeHere,BorderLayout.CENTER);
Next0Prev.add(clueNo1,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

//adding listener to all buttons
start.addActionListener(this);
continueButton.addActionListener(this);
credits.addActionListener(this);
back2f1A.addActionListener(this);
about.addActionListener(this);
back2f1B.addActionListener(this);
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    GuessingGame gg = new GuessingGame();
    gg.setTitle("Guesing Game");
    gg.setVisible(true);
    gg.setSize(500,500);
    gg.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    gg.add(startpanel);


}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (e.getSource() == about) {
        add(aboutpanel);
        aboutpanel.setVisible(true);
        aboutpanel.repaint();
        aboutpanel.revalidate();
        startpanel.setVisible(false);
    }
    else if (e.getSource() == back2f1A){
        add(startpanel);
        startpanel.setVisible(true);
        startpanel.repaint();
        startpanel.revalidate();
        aboutpanel.setVisible(false);
    }
    else if (e.getSource() == back2f1B){
        add(startpanel);
        startpanel.setVisible(true);
        startpanel.repaint();
        startpanel.revalidate();
        creditpanel.setVisible(false);
    }
    else if(e.getSource() == credits){
        add(creditpanel);
        creditpanel.setVisible(true);
        creditpanel.repaint();
        creditpanel.revalidate();
        startpanel.setVisible(false);
    }
    else if(e.getSource() == start){
        add(loadingEffect);
        loadingEffect.setVisible(true);
        loadingEffect.repaint();
        loadingEffect.revalidate();
        startpanel.setVisible(false);
        Timer t = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                add(loadingEffectBtn);
                loadingEffectBtn.setVisible(true);
                loadingEffectBtn.repaint();
                loadingEffect.invalidate();
                loadingEffect.setVisible(false);
                }
                });
                t.start();
                t.setRepeats(false);
     }
    else if(e.getSource() == continueButton){
        add(Next0Prev);
        Next0Prev.setVisible(true);
        Next0Prev.repaint();
        Next0Prev.revalidate();
        loadingEffectBtn.setVisible(false);

        Timer t = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                add(LST,BorderLayout.NORTH);
                time01.setText("time: " + gTime);
                gTime--;
         Timer t = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                score01.setText("score: " + gScore);
                gScore--;     
                }
                });
                t.start();
                t.setRepeats(true);
                }
                });
                t.start();
                t.setRepeats(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jave-Newbie! This site is dedicated to providing reviews and improvements to code which already works. If you need help finding errors/fixing code, head to [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). But before you do, please read what an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is and include one in the question you will post there.

Comment: sorry if i posted here in the codereview without reading the SSCCE, because this is my first time posting here and I will try to do what is written in the SSCCE. for the mean time, I need help in fixing my problem. The code is 100% working but it have some problems.

Comment: @Java-Newbie, if it still has problems, its clearly not 100% working.

Comment: ok, now I know.

Comment: this code is missing Brackets and indentations and whatever else I stopped when I saw the last code block's last else if statement.  there isn't any way that it compiles let alone runs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not going to go through all of this code since it's like 800 lines and would take me all day, but I can give you some good general tips just by glancing at it.

- Choose better variable names.  Things like `next07`, `next08`, [...], and `p80`, `p90`, [...] don't tell anyone anything about what those variables are actually supposed to represent and will end up confusing even yourself in the long run.
- Split out your logic into different methods.  All of your processing is in the `main()` method.  Why?  Having an 800 line method is almost always the sign of a bad design.  I grant you that this rule gets stretched a little bit when it comes to Swing, but not like this.
- Any logic that you constantly repeat should be encapsulated into its own method so that it's reusable.  For example, you have all these lines where you keep making `new ActionListener()` implementations.  This could easily be turned into a method like...

.

```
public ActionListener createActionListener(JPanel add, JPanel remove) {
    return new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            f.add(add);
            f.remove(remove);
            f.setVisible(true);
            f.revalidate();
            f.repaint();
        }
    };
}
```

This could then be called again and again, which would shorten your source code dramatically.

```
next05.addActionListener(createActionListener(p90, p80));
next06.addActionListener(createActionListener(p70, p80));
//... and so on
```

You could also simply have one class which `implements ActionListener` rather than having this factory-like method.

- You've got about a thousand `Timer`s being created and within nested `ActionListener`s.  I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish with all that, but I guarantee you that's not how you need to be going about it.  Creating a new `Timer` within another `Timer`'s `ActionListener` doesn't make sense.  If you can expand upon what you're trying to do with all that logic, I might be able to provide a better alternative or design choice.
- Why are you using HTML tags in your `JLabel` when you only needed the line breaks?  You can just use `\n`.
- You don't have to have a separate `JLabel` for every question in your game.  You can just use `JLabel.setText(String)` to change one label in your frame... That goes for all of your Swing elements.  Most of them are reusable.  You have exponentially more than you need.

I'm sure there's a lot more, but that's what I noticed off the bat.  If you shorten the code a bit given the above comments, I'll take a deeper look at it all.

Good luck!

Comment: i will try what you said. Thanks for the tips, it helps me a lot.